# How to cherry-pick a gerrit with all dependencies?

Tags: git, version-control, cherry-pick

Let's say there is are a few gerrits with dependencies :

```
A <- B <- C
```

(C depends on B and B depends on A)

If I simply cherry-pick C, it will not work because the dependencies (A and B) will not be cherry-picked.

How can I **easily** cherry-pick C such that in my local tree, all its dependencies will be applied automatically in **one command** ?

Comment: How is what you are looking for different from a [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)?

Comment: "a few **gerrits**"?? Don't you mean *commits*?

Answer (score 1):

If all of A, B and C have been submitted, you can consider `git merge`:

```
git merge C --no-ff
# merge commit does not invoke the hook commit-msg, so
# if your Gerrit requires Change-Id and you want to push
# the merged commits for review, use amend-commit to generate it
git commit --amend
```

If at least one of them has not been submitted, use `git cherry-pick` instead:

```
git cherry-pick HEAD..C --no-merges
```

`HEAD..C` is equivalent to all the commits reachable from C and new to the current branch. `--no-merges` excludes the merge commits among them. In an ideal case, merge commits don't involve conflicts and you don't need to cherry-pick them. If you do want to cherry-pick a merge commit, it's a bit annoying as you have to specify which parent to be the mainline.

If C and its ancestors are not available in the local yet, you need to fetch them first:

```
git fetch origin <refspec_of_C>
```

You can find the refspec of C on C's page. It's a ref like `refs/changes/xx/xxxxx/x`. If C has been submitted to a branch, you can fetch the branch instead.

Comment: I am aware of these methods, but I was hoping for a easy one-command method.